# Видимость класса одного решения в другом решении в VS C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, visual-studio, классы, делегаты

Доброго дня, перед мною виникла проблема, а саме видимість класу одного рішення в іншому. Рішення я пов'язав через посилання, але все ж до класу я так і не зміг дістатися. Чи можливо якось передати методи класу через делегати, або якось іншим методом, щоб не компілювати клас в dll файл?

Comment: это русскоязычное сообщество. постарайтесь перевести вопрос на русский, чтобы больше людей могло вам помочь

Comment: Под словом «рішення» вы имели в виду solution или project? Ну й будь ласка перекладіть вже російською.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс должен быть публичным в dll сборке. Чтобы он был виден в другом проекте, где **присутствует ссылка на эту сборку**. Этого будет вполне достаточно.

```
//Assembly 1
namespace Assembly1 {
    public class Foo { }
}

//Assembly 2
namespace Assembly2 {
    public class Bar {
        void Function() {
            Assembly1.Foo foo = new Assembly1.Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Соответственно, Assembly2 должна содержать ссылку на Assembly1.